# Typescript: export was not found / JSX element type does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, package

I want to use my Typescript React Component Library as a Package.

My files looks like this:

MyComponent.tsx:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export interface IProps {
 prop1: boolean;
}

const HeaderWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100vw;
`;

const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<IProps> = ({prop1}: IProps) => (
  <HeaderWrapper prop1={prop1}><h1>Test</h1></HeaderWrapper>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

index.ts

```
export * from './components/MyComponent';
```

I have no errors and can use the component.
Then I run `tsc` with `declaration: true`. And then I publish my dist folder to npm.

When I install the package in another project I use it like that:

```
import MyComponent from 'my-package';
```

When I am building the project I get following error:

```
export 'default' (imported as 'MyComponent') was not found in 'my-package'
```

&

```
TS2604: JSX element type 'MyComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

I try

```
'export {default as MyComponent} from './components/MyComponent';
```

and

```
'export * as MyComponent from './components/MyComponent';
```

But it also doesn't work.
The only solution was to import the component like that in the new project:

```
import MyComponent from 'my-package/dist/components/MyComponent';
```

But I want to use it the way with the index file.
Can somebody help me please?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very dumb.

I have to use the package like this:

```
import { MyComponent } from 'my-package';
```

Of course this works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object destructuring`.

Use this code

```
import { MyComponent } from 'my-package';
```

Instead of

```
import MyComponent from 'my-package';
```